# Term for someone who asks you a "pick one side" question and gives you a hard time on the side you choose

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

Is there a particular word or phrase for this scenario:

1. Person A poses Person B with a "pick one side" question.
2. Person B answers with he/she honest opinion
3. Person A criticizes Person B for the side he/she chose.
4. Person B defends his/her position while Person A continues to criticize.
5. Person B finally flips the question on Person A.
6. Person A replies that he/she does not have any ties to either side of the argument and walks away from the conversation.
7. Person B is left emotional and confused on the argument that just occurred.

Specifically, is there a philosophy category for this (ex. logical fallacies, ad hominem, etc.)?

Comment: I feel like there's a story here... :)

Comment: Languages have terms for many things, but it’s rare that a concept that takes four lines of text to describe in great detail has a single-word name. I highly doubt there is a term for this.

Comment: My younger cousin was asked the "Team Edward or Team Jacob" question by her classmate who hates Twilight.

Comment: I'd call that person an ass.

Comment: If you're looking the name of an argument, you might have luck at philosophy.SE.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **troll**? While commonly used to a term for people acting as to illicit an emotional reaction *on the internet*, I think it can also apply to real life.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_%28Internet%29):

> In Internet slang, a troll (/ˈtroʊl/, /ˈtrɒl/) is a person who sows discord on the Internet by starting arguments or upsetting people, by posting inflammatory, extraneous, or off-topic messages in an online community (such as a forum, chat room, or blog) with the deliberate intent of provoking readers into an emotional response or of otherwise disrupting normal on-topic discussion.

Other similar terms are:

*provocateur, antagoniser*